String to number in case of having millions of unique values
I am currently working on preprocessing big data dataset for ML purposes. I am struggling with encoding strings as numbers. I have a dataset of multiple blockchain transactions and I have addresses of sender and receivers for these transactions. I use pyspark.
I've tried String Indexer but it throws out of memory errors due to number of unique values. How should I approach it? Is hasing with SHA256 and casting to big int good approach? Wouldn't big numbers influence ML methods too much? (i will try different methods ex. random forests, gan, some based on distance etc)

What do you want to predict at the end? do you think that the full adress is necessary? maybe only the zip code (or even part of it) would be enough? or just the city/country?
